# Python 2.7: How to split on first occurrence?

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

I am trying to split a string I extract on the first occurrence of a comma. I have tried using the `split`, but something is wrong, as it doesn't split.

```
for i in range(len(items)):
    alldata = items[i].getText().encode('utf-8').split(',', 1)
    csvfile.writerow(alldata)
```

The variable `items` contains the data I extract from an URL. The output in the CSV file is put in one column. I want it to be on two columns. An example of the data (`alldata`) I get in the CSV file, looks like this:

```
['\n\n\n1958\n\n\nGeorge Lees\n']
```

Using this data as an example, I need the year `1958` to be on one column, and the name `George Lees` to be on another column instead of the new lines.

**EDIT**
Forgot to mention what I meant with the commas. The reason why I mentioned the commas is that I also tried splitting on whitespaces. When I did that I got the data:

```
['1958', 'George', 'Lees']
```

So what I tried to achieve was to split the data on the first comma occurrence. That's why I did `split(',', 1)` forgetting that I also need to split on whitespaces. So my problem is that I don't know how I split on both the first commas occurence, so that the year is on oe column and the whole name is on another column. I got

```
    ['\n\n\n1958\n\n\nGeorge Lees\n']
```

When I tried to split with `split(',', 1)`

Comment: ...but that data doesn't have any commas.

Comment: This smells like an XY problem. Ask about your actual problem, not about a solution you perceive  to be the correct one.

Comment: Also, why does your CSV file have so many newline characters?

Comment: My bad, have edited the OP

Comment: You cannot split on commas because your data doesn't have any. Commas in your output after splitting on spaces are not in your data. It's an array (list) and it's ALREADY SPLITTED.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **strip** to remove all spaces in the start & end and then use **split** by "\n" to get the required output. I have also used the **filter** method to remove any empty string or values.

**Ex:**

```
A = ['\n\n\n1958\n\n\nGeorge Lees\n']
print filter(None, A[0].strip().split("\n"))
```

**Output:**

```
['1958', 'George Lees']
```